# Changing values in a xml file using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am currently in my first year of my apprenticeship for system integration. As such, programming and scripting took and take a lesser role in my daily routine. I provide this information to illustrate my level, or rather lack there of, of programming.

Nevertheless I was tasked with writing a powershell script, which will collect information from an csv-file and then manipulate an xml file based on said input.

As of now my script is able to read out the csv file and open the xml for manipulation.
My struggle lies within the structure of said xml file itself. Structure and excerpt below

Structure:

```
<UserIntentions mediaName="CODE\win_b64\renamed_file.media" mediaVersion="421">
<SetVariable name="component_one" value="true"/>
<SetVariable name="component_two" value="3DPASS_TOMEE_PORT"/>
<SetVariable name="component_three" value="CERTIFICATES_DIR"/>
```

Code:

```
[xml]$file = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot"\req\targetfile_Template.xml"
$file.UserIntentions.SetVariable.Value = $value
```

As you can see the tag  repeats over and over.
Thus, at least to my understanding, I cannot work with something like shown above, as I would change all values at once.

I tried, of course, google before, but all examples I came across had a more precise xml structure where tags(?) did not double.

I need to be able to change the individual entrys, picked by name. To do so I tried using where-object, but to no effect but errors.
Then, I tried the following:

```
if($file.UserIntention.SetVariable.name -eq $intention)
{$file.UserIntention.SetVariable.value = $value}
```

This, however, has the same result, since the condition needs to be met just once for all to change.

So, what I hope to get an explanation for: how can I change an individual value in my structure above, filtered by name? Please keep in mind I never worked with xml before, and barely touched powershell.

Kind regards and many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7) script block in case there are multiple attributes that fit the criteria. [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) will allow you to create a filter condition.

```
$file.UserIntentions.SetVariable | Where Name -eq $intention | Foreach-Object {
    $_.Value = $value
}
```

Comment: Dear AdminOfThings,

first of all, thank you for your answer. Seeing that my approach with "where" was not entirely wrong is somewhat comforting.

I added you answer to my code and tried to run it, but it causes an error, or rather requires an input.

Console Output below:

cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:

It clearly requires some form of input, but I don't know yet why, or what for that matter. Can you tell me?

Kind regards
Tschuangtse